# Visual Basic Output

Tags: basic

This is for a task I'm doing at the university. The following code is provided.
[Code and the data given.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtcnK.png)

The question is what will be returned for the given data set and my answer was, False 5 times. I've been asked by my tutor to recheck that answer and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The function returns *a* `Boolean`. `Return` causes the function to exit.

Comment: This function checks if DATA table contains a value equal to VAL argument. This function returns False for data provided by you.

Comment: The dataset is given along with the value provided. The question is about that specific dataset and value.

Comment: That's not valid code for any version of Visual Basic that I'm aware of.  `As Integer()`? `End For`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function checks 5 values in the FOR loop, but never returns to the caller. After that the FOR loop has ended, the function returns with return value of "FALSE"